# Disable StreetView navigation to non connected photospheres

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Since StreetVew has no levels (floors), I am facing huge problems on multilevel tours because the navigation jumps from floor to floor (the panos are actually really close to each other but on different floors, and are not directly connected). I guess that by disabling one of the two navigation methods will do the trick, I just can't find it in the API.
I am embedding photospheres through MAPS API with the following code:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
function initialize() {
  google.maps.streetViewViewer = 'photosphere';
  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById('pano'), {
      pano: 'PANOID',
      pov: {heading: 348.27, pitch: -1.62, zoom: 0.26},
      linksControl: true,
      zoomControl: true,
      zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
      },
      scaleControl: false,
      overviewMapControl: false,
      panControl: false,
      visible: true,
      motionTracking: false,
      motionTrackingControl: false
  });
}
```

What is the option to disable the right arrow from the screenshot (the one with a circle around the arrow) if it exists at all?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZDyB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option is called "clickToGo" and should be set to false.

I searched for it and couldn't find, so I decided to go through all the options and experiment, and bumped into it...

Answer (score 1):

Indeed set clickToGo to false to disable the donut.

Besides that, Streetview supports floors, since when you publish a panorama you have these properties :

```
pose.heading
pose.latLngPair
pose.pitch
pose.roll
pose.level
pose.altitude
connections
places
```

cf: https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/reference/rest/v1/photo/update

multifoor example : https://goo.gl/maps/nDvPsbDakLN2